# What in React should actually be rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am currently working on learning React and Redux. Now I am getting a better grasp on what the two do:

- **React** - *Render components on the page*
- **Redux** - *Keep the state of the page*

My question though is: what should I actually be rendering with React? Is React suppose to render the entire page, even the header that won't change? For instance, am I suppose to create a new component for the header (logo and tabs, not changing), or just add that to the HTML file I will be rendering to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest adding absolutely everything as a React component. Have a single `<div>` in your html file that you mount your React app to. I found that when I started using React I would try and avoid writing extra code (sure, writing a component for a header rather than the raw HTML is extra lines).

But this introduces complexity, in a way. Different parts of your app are rendered differently. In the long run, in my experience, consistency and readability is more important than fewer lines of code.

BTW if you're using [stateless functional components](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#stateless-functions) (which your header would be), it's barely any extra code.

```
import React from 'react';
export default Header = () => <header>My wonderful app</header>;
```

Answer (score 3):

like most other frameworks, you will have your base 'index.html' file that will include all of your dependencies and then a body which contains a div that you will render your react components into. it will look something like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
  <-- script, css, framework files added here -->
  </head>
  <body> 
    <div id="reactApp"</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

then your main app file in react will have something along the lines of this at the bottom:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
    document.getElementById('reactApp')
);
```

everything else can be rendered within React and passed along to that div view.

Answer (score 1):

It's entirely possible to have a hybrid page. For example: keep the navbar as native HTML where as the content is React.

Remember, React is component oriented so you could think of it as small widgets.

However, you will often have different widgets share the same state. In this case, it's good to make them part of the same tree of components.

Your question doesn't have a definite answer. It depends on what your application state needs are, but use React for the dynamic pieces of your page. Those parts that you're thinking are going to change without a reload will probably keep a state, so that's where React's stage management could come in handy.